# Flutter How to achieve: Click to take photos and long press to record

Tags: flutter, dart

Photo and video are combined into one button. Click to take photos and long press to record. I want to achieve two effects at the same time. How can I do it?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`GestureDetector` widget might be what you need. It has callbacks for both tap and long press: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget, it has APIs for both `onTap` and `onLongPress`.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => _takePicture(),
            onLongPress: () => _takeVideo(),
            child: Text('Click me'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _takePicture() => print('Taking a picture!');

  void _takeVideo() => print('Taking a video!');
}
```

---

Here's the [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev) tutorial on how to use the camera API.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

Answer (score 0):

You can use OutlineButton Class, it has the pressed and onLongPress Methods.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OutlineButton(
            onTap: () => takePicture(),
            onLongPress: () => takeVideo(),
            child: Text('Click me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but how do you detect release events within the takeVideo function?